# Retrieve records and convert them into new with string functions

Tags: php, mysql, string

This is too complicated to me so I need your help

I have a database named "recipes" with a table name "posts" which has a field "content" and contains recipes in the following form:

```
Ingredients\r\n
1 tomato\r\n\
2 eggs\r\n
500 gr olive oil\r\n 
etc...

Instructions\r\n
Do this do that\r\n 
etc...
```

I need to convert this record to:

```
<div class="Ingredients">
<div class="name"> must be string from field "post_name" from table "posts" 
<li class="ingredient">1 tomato</li>
<li class="ingredient">2 eggs</li>
<li class="ingredient">500 gr olive oil</li>
</ul>
<div class-"Instructions"</div>
<ol>

<div class="instruction">Do this do that etc...
</div>
```

So I need the following things:

1. Connect with database and retrieve data from content field from
   table posts
2. Search for all numbers and add before of them, the li tag until
   meets the word Ingredients.
3. Finds all the li tags AFTER the word "Instructions" and delete them. (This happens because many of recipes has li tags after the word "instructions" which must be erased)
4. Find all the li tags and add class="ingredient" to them.
5. Adding some "class text" at the end of the
   last closing li tag.
6. Replace all the old records from field content
   with the new ones

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT: What i have done so far is connection with database

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br /><hr />";
mysql_select_db("word") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8'");
echo "Connected to Database<br /><hr />";
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['ID'] . " - " . $row['post_title'];
echo "<br /n>"; 
}
?>
```

EDIT2: The problem with greek characters solved with corect encoding settings in chrome browser
So far so good. Now i need code to replace characters UNTIL meet the word "Instructions" 
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know how to do any of the steps - like how to connect to a database?

Comment: yes i know how to connect with database. The most difficult is to find numbers and add li tag before them and to elliminate all li tags after the word instructions. Too complicated for a newbee like me.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Pick a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that suits your style and needs.

**Step 2**

Read the documentation associated with that and follow along with some simple examples.

**Step 3**

Application!

Doing this from first principles is extremely difficult and time consuming compared to using a framework.

The mechanical translation from `\r\n` (you have `/r/n` which is totally different, presumably a typo) to `<br>` is something most frameworks have methods for.

Anything beyond that is custom code, but you haven't really done anything other than list out a specification. Stack Overflow is not to be confused with a place where you hire coders.

What you're describing here is a fairly simple thing if you know anything about PHP's string and array manipulation techniques, all of which are described in [the documentation](http://php.net/).

Comment: Sorry for /r/n. The correct is \r\n. I'm trying to combine some string technics and also looking every technic to match for my needs. I' ve also convert this database by replacing all strings with many spaces to one space, some upercase to lowercase etc. one step at a time.